# Finding epsilon during a limit proof by working backwards

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

For finding an epsilon is it wrong to work backwards from what my end result should be to what I am given?

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to MSE! Please write the problem you are currently solving and type the text instead of putting it on a picture.

Comment: yes, it would be helpful to provide more context.  without that it's hard to provide assistance.  Additionally, it seems like something is going wrong when you say "if $n-x = n$ and $n = n+1$".